# How to get list of palindrome in text?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following interview question that may require traversing through the entire string.

- **Problem** I searched about find Problem and most people do it like this `def palindrome(s): return s==s[::-1]` But this task is diffrent?
- **palindrome** is a word the can read from both directions like 'mam', 'dad'. Your task is to get a list of **palindrome** in a given string.

```py
def palindrome(s):

  stack = []
  return ['aaa']
```

exampls

```py
palindrome('aaa') #['aaa']
palindrome('abcbaaaa') #['abcba','aaaa']
palindrome('xrlgabccbaxrlg') #['abccba']
palindrome('abcde') #['']
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @ElPandario how can he find the outputs? assume outputs are not present.

Comment: Pleas do not spam languages.  Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to avoid checking all the possible combinations :). My idea is, start from the extremities and converge:

```
def palindrome(s):
    out = [''] #we need the list to not be empty for the following check
    for main_start in range(len(s) - 1):
        for main_end in range(len(s) - 1, main_start, -1):
            start = main_start
            end = main_end
            while (end - start) > 0:
                if s[start] == s[end]: ##may be palindrome
                    start += 1
                    end -= 1
                else:
                    break
            else:
                if s[main_start:main_end + 1] not in out[-1]: #ignore shorter ("inner") findings
                    out.append(s[main_start:main_end + 1])
    return out[1:] #skip the dummy item
```